# Como receber um array no body de uma rota nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http-request, ejs

Tenho um código que retorna um objeto no formato json para mim e gostaria de criar uma página que o Body recebesse isso. porém, não consigo criar de jeito nenhum.

Estou usando EJS...
fiz assim para receber minha rota

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("secao/home");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Servidor rodando");
});
```

Então gostaria que na home recebesse o array de aqui.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "hostname": [
    "{{accountName}}",
    "{{environment}}",
    "com",
    "br"
    ],
    "path": [
    "api",
    "catalog_system",
    "pvt",
    "category",
    "tree",
    "{{categoryLevels}}",
    ""
    ],
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-vttt-api-appkey-api-appkey": "{{X-Vtt-API-AppKey}}",
        "x-vttt-api-apptoken": "{{X-Vtt-API-AppToken}}"
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(body.toString());
    });
});
req.end();
```

Como prosseguir?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o array direto pelo 'res.render', criando uma variável ou mesmo uma função!
Primeiro Ex.

```
app.get('/rota', function(req, res){
     res.render('pagina', {nomeVariavel: nomeArray}); })
})
```

Segundo Ex, no seu caso.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.render('secao/home', {options: options}); })
})
```